Using graphql in magento 2.4.7-p2 error on fresh instalation
I have fresh install of magento 2.4.7-p2 using warden. I installed sample data. Now i want to acess graphql using link https://app.demo.test/graphql But i have error.
{
"errors": [
{
"message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>",
"locations": [
{
"line": 1,
"column": 1
}
],
"extensions": {
"file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Language/Parser.php",
"line": 433
}
}
]
}

Any solution for this ? Same error happens on 2.4.7. No idea prev. versions.

If this is a fresh installation without any modifications: please report this as a bug to the maintainers of Magento

This is proper action. Since body was empty. If you make request using some client, the response will show up.
